# Node.js assert.deepEqual 2 values

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, assert, mocha.js

I have a some function which sends 2 objects:

```
    function A(){
        var message = {
            cmd: 'one',
            msg: {
                type: 'test',
                id: 1
        }

        sendTest(message)
        message = {
             cmd: 'two',
             msg: {
                 type: 'test_a',
                 id: 2
        }
        sendTest(message)
}
```

Can I use assert.deepEqual in unit test for testing "message" with 2 different objects?

Maybe it looks like `assert.deepEqual(message, test_message1 || test_message2)`

or `(assert.deepEqual(message, test_message1) || assert.deepEqual(message, test_message2))`

Comment: What's wrong with two assertions? `assert.deepEqual(message, test_message1); assert.deepEqual(message, test_message2)`

Comment: in this case 1 of 2 asserts precisely fail. I wish "universal" solution

Comment: You can use `assert` how many times you want in a single test, you don't need to limit yourself to use only one assert per test case. The "universal solution" is to call `assert` as many times as you need!

Comment: I don't limit myself to use one assert per test. I wish just test a moment when actual "message" will be one of two expected "messages"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chai uses the deep-eql library to perform deep equal checks. This shows how to use it to check that an object is deeply equal to one object in a set. Here the object we test is `q` and we want to make sure it is deeply equal to at least one of `message1` or `message2`. Change `q` to some random value to see the test fail. The code is written to easily check against a longer list of possible messages.

```
var assert = require("chai").assert;
var eql = require("deep-eql");

var message1 = {
    cmd: 'one',
    msg: {
        type: 'test',
        id: 1
    }
};

var message2 = {
    cmd: 'two',
    msg: {
        type: 'test_a',
        id: 2
    }
};

var q = {
    cmd: 'one',
    msg: {
        type: 'test',
        id: 1
    }
};

var found;
var candidates = [message1, message2];

for(var i = 0; !found && i < candidates.length; ++i)
    if (eql(candidates[i], q))
        found = candidates[i];

assert.isDefined(found, "did not find a match");
```